# Free tool for WiFi quality assessment

Tags: wireless-networking, benchmarking

I found this neat and dead-simple [DIY project](http://www.freeantennas.com/projects/template2/index.html) for boosting a WiFi AP's antenna range, and I was wondering how I could actually do a before/after benchmark.

Are there any free tools that could test the quality of a WiFi network? I'm thinking of walking around my appartment with my netbook in hand and eventually end up with a 'coverage map'.

Most searches I tried ended up in some wardriving tool or another - they don't seem to fit for my purpose, but correct me if I'm wrong.

What I'd like the tool to have (a subset is fine, but the more, the better):
- show the instantaneous signal strength, and not just with a 1-5 bars resolution as Windows does. I want hard numbers.

- do a throughput test (U/L, D/L). For this, I guess I could use a 2nd computer on the same subnet, wired directly to the AP, and try a large file transfer.
- do a latency check on the local LAN

So, any suggestions?

Comment: Tried `ping`? .

Comment: Ping by itself doesn't saturate the connection. I could try a `ping` while doing a big file transfer, but it would be nice to have a program do the manual work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always liked inSSIDer or Chanalyzer from MetaGeek.

Comment: Channalyzer, if I understand correctly, only works with their 2.4GHz analyzer USB dongles. However, inSSIDer also works with builtin WiFi cards and is AWESOME!

Comment: +1 for a good solution on Windows/Mac (?); -1 for not briefing the Unix/Linux community that there isn't a native version.

Answer (score 4):

[iPerf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/), perhaps ?

> Iperf was developed by NLANR/DAST as a
>   modern alternative for measuring
>   maximum TCP and UDP bandwidth
>   performance. Iperf allows the tuning
>   of various parameters and UDP
>   characteristics. Iperf reports
>   bandwidth, delay jitter, datagram
>   loss.

---

[Xirrus WiFi tool](http://www.xirrus.com/library/wifitools.php) is another option
[image]

Comment: your IPerf link is slightly wrong and I don't have enough rep to edit it.